# Cannot detect any serial ports with Python

Tags: python, serial-port

I am trying to find the correct com port a device is connected to before being able to run the rest of the Python script.

I have tried using this:

```
    import serial.tools.list_ports
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for p in ports:
        print p
```

And this:

```
    import wmi
    c = wmi.WMI()
    wql = "Select * From Win32_SerialPort"
    for item in c.query(wql):
        print item
```

And this:

```
    def serial_ports():

    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(256)]
        print ports 
    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
        # this excludes your current terminal "/dev/tty"
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')

    result = []
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port)
            s.close()
            result.append(port)
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
            pass
    return result
```

All of these methods are ones that I have found from other stack exchange posts; however, with both functions, when I try to print the list of com ports I get a blank list? Any help/insights would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: do you actually have any com ports? newer pcs don't have any at all, since that's prehistory legacy hardware, and new machines are going legacy-free

Comment: Yes! Sorry I did not make that clear in my previous post, but when I enter the com port number in manually/hard code it in it works fine. I am trying to automate the process of finding the correct com port my device is connected to by first getting a list of all com ports and trying them all.

Comment: Did you find the solution? or you still have some problem ?

Comment: I still have the same problem! Would appreciate any help if you have any ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
import serial,os,sys,glob


def serial_ports():

    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(256)]
        print ports 
    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
        # this excludes your current terminal "/dev/tty"
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')

    result = []
    print ports
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port,9600)
            s.close()
            result.append(port)
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
            pass
    return result

print serial_ports()
```

**Never can open any `serial` port without speed (clock) definition.**

On linux : `run as root`, normal user can't access `/dev` (Don't change permission cos name_space creating dynamically. Bad idea !).